# I got upset [ with / from ] the phone call

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I've quite seen a lot of both cases but I couldn't tell what's the difference here. Please help.

Comment: I’d use “from”. Using “with” sounds a bit like the phone call is being treated as an individual: *I got upset with the doctor.* But even using “from” the sentence is not very idiomatic. The more common phrasing is, *I was upset by the the phone call.* or *The phone call was upsetting.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few prepositions that can be used after *upset*:

> They’re all still very upset **about** losing the case.
>
> He was upset **over** a disagreement with his boss.
>
> I am still upset **by** what you said.

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upset_1) lists *by*, *over* and *about* as the prepositions used with *upset*. But there may be some other ones:

> He was upset **at** missing all the excitement.
>
> I think she may be a bit upset **with** you.
>
> (from [Online Oxford Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=upset))

*From* after *upset* is definitely not the most common choice. Click [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upset%20from%2Cupset%20with%2Cupset%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupset%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20about%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cupset%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20about%3B%2Cc0) for details. It doesn't mean that *upset* and *from* can't be found together: But as their life improved financially, she continued to get *upset from* time to time. But it's about the phrase *from time to time*.

All in all, *about*, *by* and *over* should be interchangeable (I was upset by/over/about the phone call). If you want to mention a person after *upset*, *with* or *at* may be the best choice:

> I don't know what I've done to make you upset **at** me. ([source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=LejuYR5EUUMC&pg=PA132&dq=%22upset%20at%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1-ozrmNDnAhVD7WEKHeYhDsMQ6wEIWDAF#v=onepage&q=%22upset%20at%22&f=false))
>
> Husbands, if your wife is upset **with** you, go to her and understand why she is upset. ([source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ZbX5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22upset%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWnuixmdDnAhWJH3AKHY9xDcUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22upset%20with%22&f=false))

Comment: Thank you. Frankly, I was wondering "to get turned on [ with / from ]", but I was afraid of getting my post deleted, so I changed it. Could you be nice and explain what's the difference between "with" and "from" here?

Comment: @dolco Please post another question about it because you are asking about a totally different verb. You'll be able to get better answers like that. 